# My CI model class with static method is failing

Tags: php, codeigniter

OK...first I read this article..

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters/

In the first hack, it says if I include these in my `config.php` file:

```
function __autoload($class) {  
    if (file_exists(APPPATH."models/".strtolower($class).EXT)) {  
        include_once(APPPATH."models/".strtolower($class).EXT);  
    }  
}
```

I don't need to extend my model class to CI_Model.

Then the I tried to use `$this->db->select('email')->from('users')->where('email', $email);` in my model class..CodeIgniter tells me "db" property is not found. Has anyone tried this hack before and know how to get it to work?

```
class User {

public $id;
public $email;
public $displayName;
public $password;

public static function search_by_email($email) {
    $user = new User;

    $user->db->select('email')->from('users')->where('email', $email);
    $query = $user->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows()==0) {
        return false;
    }else {
        foreach ($query->result() as $key => $val) {
            $user->email = $val['email'];
            $user->displayName = $val['displayName'];
           return $user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I call the static function in my controller I use:

```
        $user = User::search_by_email("xxx@gmail.com");
```

If I don't extend User, it will show a CI warning: `Message: Undefined property: User::$db`. If I use `User extends CI_Model {}`, the server will crash.

Does anyone have an idea about this situation?

---

Edited:

Then I dumped the silly Nettus' tutorial code, thanks to you guys...but my model is still not working:

```
class User extends CI_Model {

    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $displayName;
    public $password;
public function search_by_email($email) {

        $user = new User();

        $this->db->select('email')->from('users')->where('email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows()==0) {
            return false;
        }else {
            foreach ($query->result() as $key => $val) {
                $user->email = $val['email'];
                $user->displayName = $val['displayName'];
               return $user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

In my controller I use:

```
$this->load->model('User');

$user = $this->User->search_by_email("leo.niecn@gmail.com");
```

My server still crashed.....am I forbidden to write class variables like `public $id` in my model?

Comment: What `$user->db` is supposed to be? Your `User` class doesn't even define it.

Comment: If I extend from CI_Model, db is a property defined within CI_Model. The tutorial from Nettus tells me that I don't need to extend from CI_Model anymore as long as I paste some code to config.php file..then I did, and then this "hack" didn't work.

Comment: You realise that article is almost three years old, right?

Comment: @Wind Dweller: if a property isn't defined - it won't appear there magically.

Comment: :'( I know..I thought adding these lines to config.php will somehow make User model inherits from CI_Model...guess I'm wrong. Still! If I add class User extends CI_Model..the server will crash..

Comment: this is so expected. you can see this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMfgtVkZc7M) and check how loading the model is loaded there.

Comment: I know the "normal" way of using Codeigniter..I'm just trying to be more modular and fully utilize PHP's OOP feature

Answer (score 1):

This part of code doesn't make any sense:

```
function __autoload($class) {  
   if (file_exists(APPPATH . "models/" . strtolower($class).EXT)) {  
       include_once(APPPATH . "models/" . strtolower($class).EXT);  
   }  
}
```

as long as you can load your model from `autoload.php` under `config` folder or just do the following when you need the model:

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

then just call your function.

Comment: I tried this method..still not working...but thanks for pointing out the nettuts' tutorial not making sense.

Comment: @WindDweller - Hi, can you post here what the error you're getting once you use this method?!